# Уведомлять пользователей telegram через определённый промежуток времени Golang

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, golang, циклы, время

У меня есть телеграмм бот, который по взаимодействию с пользователем работает по типу "Запрос-ответ". Необходимой функцией этого бота является уведомлять пользователей в 9 утра о том, что нужно ввести новые данные с которыми он будет работать.
Проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю, как мне проверять текущее время периодически, поскольку код, который я использую для телеграмм бота, заканчивается входом в цикл
for update := range updates , но внутри этого цикла, судя по логированию, я попадаю только, когда получаю сообщения от пользователя. Скорее всего я не до конца понимаю некоторых особенностей методов go-telegram-bot-api

```
func main() {
    // используя токен создаем новый инстанс бота
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI(telegramBotToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    bot.Debug = true
    log.Printf("Авторизация аккаунта бота %s", bot.Self.UserName)
    // u - структура с конфигом для получения апдейтов
    u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
    u.Timeout = 1
    // используя конфиг u создаем канал в который будут прилетать новые сообщения
    updates := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)
    err = callAt(11, 17, 0, myfunc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
    //обработка сообщений
    for update := range updates {
        reply := "Не знаю что сказать"
        msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID, reply)
        msg.ReplyMarkup = board_StartCommand
        if update.Message == nil {
            continue
        }
        if _, err := bot.Send(msg); err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }

    }
}
```